# Per session caching issue

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies

I have a WordPress website and it's hosted by Hostgator.

- I have two versions of the homepage which are served depending on the detected user agent.
- Now the problem is that the user agent is not detected correctly on the first visit, but only on the second visit.
- Another thing I've found that if I delete the cookies after the first visit (specifically: `PHPSESSID`) it does not detect the right user agent as long as i keep deleting the cookie after each page view.

These are the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` values I am getting:

First view (the incorrect one):
`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 6680.78.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.102 Safari/537.36`

Second view (the correct one):
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53`

Any idea how can I prevent this sort of caching?

Comment: once you have detected the user agent, you can store it with the current session id as a session variable to keep it . Regarding first time visitor, you can do a redirect but that will be visible to the user (maybe a intro page etc)

Comment: Are you using `get_browser()`?

Comment: @zgr024 nope, I'm parsing the user agent variable

Comment: The best way to do it is with JavaScript, but if you want to do it using PHP, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php though you will need browscap.ini. There is also a function written on that page in a comment that works well since the user agent variable tends to be a little off sometimes

Comment: Can you provide an example of the different User-Agent responses you are getting from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`?

Comment: @zgr024 edited the question, added the user agent values. Thanks

Comment: Is the issue still happening on PC/Other devices? Or is it just localized to iOS?

Comment: Just tested Android. Happens on all mobile devices we've tested